# NAS mountable through mount.cifs but not through fstab

Tags: debian, cifs

I tried to reconnect my NAS (`cifs`) on my fresh Debian 9.0. I can mount it through the following `mount.cifs` command:

```
mount -t cifs //mynas/Photos -o credentials=/root/.smbcredentials,rw,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0644,dir_mode=0755,uid=1000,gid=1000 /media/mynas/Photos
```

Then, I can browse its content, read & write files…
However, when I try to mount it through my `fstab`, it's ignored:

```
//mynas/Photos /media/mynas/Photos cifs credentials=/root/.smbcredentials,rw,noauto,uid=1000,gid=1000,file_mode=0644,dir_mode=0755,iocharset=utf8 0 0
```

When I run `mount -av`, I get:

```
/media/mynas/Photos     : ignoré (Ignored)
```

Do you have an idea of how I could solve this ?
Thanks.

Comment: That's what "noauto" means, it's skipped by `mount -a`. Does it work when you run `sudo mount /media/mynas/Photos` ?

Comment: It works when I remove the `noauto` option, thanks. There are other problems now, but this one is solved!